# websocket почему работают быстрее чем http?

Tags: архитектура, websocket

Почему **websocket** работают в **100 раз** **быстрее** чем методы **http** протокола. И в каких случаях лучшее использовать **http**?

То есть насколько вебсокеты являются универсальной пулей.

Comment: в случае http запросов каждый раз происходит установка соединения - длительная и дорогостоящая операция

Comment: Как это число получилось-то?

Comment: Ну я смотрел докалады с higload++. И там расказывали про решения подключений к бд.

Comment: а можно ссылку на доклад? мне эта тема тоже весьма интересна

Comment: @IDONTSUDO из своей практики - http используется только при загрузке страницы, весь остальной обмен сервера с клиентом только по ws. ws фулдуплекс обмен данными клиента и сервера. это то что недоставало для нормальной работы. до появления ws городили такие велосипеды  как comet.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXDeYrUV7SI @muturgan

Comment: Не сильно универсально. Потому что самостоятельный бинарный протокол. Для http существуют также "server sent events", которые тоже 1 раз открывают коннект и не закрывают его. Работает в одну сторону и не бинарный, но зато http

Comment: @IDONTSUDO благодарю)

Answer (score 1):

http://drewww.github.io/socket.io-benchmarking/ здесь описаны практики как лучше использовать сокеты.

Если в кратце то **с каждым новым websocket падает производительность**.

*Почему **websocket** быстрее.*

Потому что **websocket не закрывает соединение**
**И не ждет ответа после запроса**

**В отличие от http**
Http открывает соединение шлет запрос ждет пока вернется ответ закрывает соединение
websocket открывает соединение и кидает запросы не дожидаясь уведомлений при этом не закрывая соединения. Поэтому КПД больше, и скорость работы выше.

От этого websocket и быстрее

Comment: Необходимо добавить, что кпд передачи ws намного больше чем http.

Comment: Спасибо поправил

Comment: Что то непонятно: Сначала - "с каждым новым websocket падает производительность.", а в конце - "Поэтому КПД больше, и скорость работы выше."

Comment: Шел 2019 год, а есть люди, которые думают, что протокол Http 1.0 - это последняя версия и после каждого ответа сервер реально закрывает соединение ?